# Android Image/Video incorrectly rotated 90 degrees counter clockwise

Tags: android, android-layout, android-camera

I have an app that that exposes the android Camera API, my goal is to use the Camera in my activity “ScanVinFromBarcodeActivity” , in order to scan barcodes using (zxing liberary).

**The issue I'm facing is that the Camera output on the preview (SurfaceView) seems to be rotated 90 degrees counter clockwise (portrait & landscape orientations).**

See the snapshot of my screen ( As you can see the people and my computer are rotated 90 degrees counter clockwise???:

By the way my device is a Galaxy S3.

[image]

**I’m using  the following code in my PreviewCamera class which extends SurfaceView**

The relevant snippet:

```
surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) method 
{
.
.
.
/*rotate the image by 90 degrees clockwise , in order to correctly displayed the image , images seem to be -90 degrees (counter clockwise) rotated 
* I even tried setting it to  p.setRotation(0); , but still no effect.

*/p.setRotation(90);
mCamera.setParameters(p);
.
.
.
}
```

But it has no effect, the image is still 90 counter clockwise, instead of the correct 0 degrees.

**CameraPreview.java 
Provides a SurfaceView in order to stream current images coming from the camera to the screen, so the uses can preview & see what the camera sees.**

```
package com.ty.ownerspoc.barcode;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo;

/** A basic Camera preview class */
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements
        SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private Context context;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;
        this.context = context;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the
        // preview.
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }
                Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();

        // get width & height of the SurfaceView
        int SurfaceViewWidth = this.getWidth();
        int SurfaceViewHeight = this.getHeight();

        List<Size> sizes = p.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
         Size optimalSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(sizes, SurfaceViewWidth, SurfaceViewHeight);


        // set parameters
        p.setPreviewSize(optimalSize.width, optimalSize.height);

        /*rotate the image by 90 degrees clockwise , in order to correctly displayed the image , images seem to be -90 degrees (counter clockwise) rotated 
         * I even tried setting it to  p.setRotation(0); , but still no effect.
         */
         p.setRotation(90);

        mCamera.setParameters(p);

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("CameraPreview ,  surfaceCreated() , orientation: ",
                    String.valueOf(e.getMessage()));
        }
    }// end surfaceChanged()
     static Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List <Camera.Size>sizes, int w, int h) {
            final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
            final double MAX_DOWNSIZE = 1.5;

            double targetRatio = (double) w / h;
            if (sizes == null) return null;

            Size optimalSize = null;
            double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

            int targetHeight = h;

            // Try to find an size match aspect ratio and size
            for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
              double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
              double downsize = (double) size.width / w;
              if (downsize > MAX_DOWNSIZE) {
                //if the preview is a lot larger than our display surface ignore it
                //reason - on some phones there is not enough heap available to show the larger preview sizes
                continue;
              }
              if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
              if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
              }
            }
            // Cannot find the one match the aspect ratio, ignore the requirement
            //keep the max_downsize requirement
            if (optimalSize == null) {
              minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
              for (Size size : sizes) {
                double downsize = (double) size.width / w;
                if (downsize > MAX_DOWNSIZE) {
                  continue;
                }
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                  optimalSize = size;
                  minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
              }
            }
            //everything else failed, just take the closest match
            if (optimalSize == null) {
              minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
              for (Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                  optimalSize = size;
                  minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
              }
            }
            return optimalSize;
          }

}//end class CameraPreview
```

**Android activity (ScanVinFromBarcodeActivity):**

Responsible for launching the camera & layout.

```
package com.ty.ownerspoc.barcode;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.google.zxing.BinaryBitmap;
import com.google.zxing.ChecksumException;
import com.google.zxing.FormatException;
import com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader; //found via import at compile time, however was found at run time 
import com.google.zxing.NotFoundException;
import com.google.zxing.RGBLuminanceSource;//found via import at compile time, however was found at run time 
import com.google.zxing.Reader;
import com.google.zxing.Result;
import com.google.zxing.common.HybridBinarizer;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.ty.ownerspoc.R;

public class ScanVinFromBarcodeActivity extends Activity {

    private Camera globalCamera;
    private int cameraId = 0;
    private TextView VINtext = null;
    private View scanButton = null;
    // bitmap from camera
    private Bitmap bmpOfTheImageFromCamera = null;
    // global flag whether a camera has been detected
    private boolean isThereACamera = false;
    // surfaceView for preview object
    private FrameLayout frameLayoutBarcodeScanner = null;
    private CameraPreview newCameraPreview = null;
    private SurfaceView surfaceViewBarcodeScanner = null;

    /*
     * This method , finds FEATURE_CAMERA, opens the camera, set parameters ,
     * add CameraPreview to layout, set camera surface holder, start preview
     */
    private void initializeGlobalCamera() {
        try {
            if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                    PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No camera on this device",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else { // check for front camera ,and get the ID
                cameraId = findFrontFacingCamera();
                if (cameraId < 0) {

                    Toast.makeText(this, "No front facing camera found.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity",
                            "camera was found , ID: " + cameraId);
                    // camera was found , set global camera flag to true
                    isThereACamera = true;
                    // OPEN
                    globalCamera = Camera.open(cameraId);

                    // pass surfaceView to CameraPreview
                    newCameraPreview = new CameraPreview(this, globalCamera);
                    // pass CameraPreview to Layout
                    frameLayoutBarcodeScanner.addView(newCameraPreview);
                    try {
                        globalCamera
                                .setPreviewDisplay(surfaceViewBarcodeScanner
                                        .getHolder());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    // PREVIEW
                    globalCamera.startPreview();

                    Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity",
                            "camera opened & previewing");
                }
            }// end else ,check for front camera
        }// end try
        catch (Exception exc) {

            // in case of exception release resources & cleanup
            if (globalCamera != null) {
                globalCamera.stopPreview();
                globalCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
                globalCamera.release();
                globalCamera = null;

            }
            Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity initializeGlobalCamera() exception:",
                    exc.getMessage());
        }// end catch
    }

    // onCreate, instantiates layouts & surfaceView used for video preview
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_barcode_vin_scanner);
        Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity", "onCreate ");

        // create surfaceView for previewing of camera image
        frameLayoutBarcodeScanner = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.FrameLayoutForPreview);
        surfaceViewBarcodeScanner = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceViewBarcodeScanner);

        initializeGlobalCamera();

        // create text area & scan button
        VINtext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytext);
        scanButton = findViewById(R.id.webbutton);
        // on click listener, onClick take a picture
        scanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {

                    // if true take a picture
                    if (isThereACamera) {
                        Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity",
                                "setOnClickListener() isThereACamera: "
                                        + isThereACamera);

                        globalCamera.takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);
                        globalCamera.stopPreview();
                        // wait 2 secs , than start preview again
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                        globalCamera.startPreview();
                    }

                }// end try
                catch (Exception exc) {

                    // in case of exception release resources & cleanup
                    if (globalCamera != null) {
                        globalCamera.stopPreview();
                        globalCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
                        globalCamera.release();
                        globalCamera = null;

                    }
                    Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity setOnClickListener() exceprtion:",
                            exc.getMessage());
                }// end catch

            }// end on Click
        });// end OnClickListener() implementation

    }// end onCreate

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity, onResume() globalCamera:",
                String.valueOf(globalCamera));

        if (globalCamera != null) {
            // START PREVIEW
            globalCamera.startPreview();
        } else {
            initializeGlobalCamera();
        }

        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {

        if (globalCamera != null) {
            globalCamera.stopPreview();
            globalCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            globalCamera.release();
            globalCamera = null;
        }
        super.onStop();
    }

    PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {

        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] imgData, Camera camera) {
            try {

                // get the bitmap from camera imageData
                bmpOfTheImageFromCamera = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
                        imgData, 0, imgData.length);
                BinaryBitmap bitmap = null;
                if (bmpOfTheImageFromCamera != null) {
                    // convert bitmap to binary bitmap
                    bitmap = cameraBytesToBinaryBitmap(bmpOfTheImageFromCamera);

                    if (bitmap != null) {
                        // decode the VIN
                        String VIN = decodeBitmapToString(bitmap);
                        Log.d("***ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity ,onPictureTaken(): VIN ",
                                VIN);
                        VINtext.setText(VIN);
                    } else {
                        Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity ,onPictureTaken(): bitmap=",
                                String.valueOf(bitmap));
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity , onPictureTaken(): bmpOfTheImageFromCamera = ",
                            String.valueOf(bmpOfTheImageFromCamera));
                }
            }// end try

            catch (Exception exc) {
                exc.getMessage();

                Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity , scanButton.setOnClickListener(): exception = ",
                        exc.getMessage());
            }
        }// end onPictureTaken()
    };// jpegCallback implementation

    private int findFrontFacingCamera() {
        int cameraId = -1;
        // Search for the front facing camera
        int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
            CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
            if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity , findFrontFacingCamera(): ",
                        "Camera found");
                cameraId = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return cameraId;
    }// end findFrontFacingCamera()

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (globalCamera != null) {
            globalCamera.stopPreview();
            globalCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            globalCamera.release();
            globalCamera = null;
        }
        super.onPause();
    }// end onPause()

    public String decodeBitmapToString(BinaryBitmap bitmap) {
        Reader reader = null;
        Result result = null;
        String textResult = null;
        try {

            reader = new MultiFormatReader();
            if (bitmap != null) {
                result = reader.decode(bitmap);
                if (result != null) {
                    textResult = result.getText();
                } else {
                    Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity , String decodeBitmapToString (BinaryBitmap bitmap): result = ",
                            String.valueOf(result));
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity , String decodeBitmapToString (BinaryBitmap bitmap): bitmap = ",
                        String.valueOf(bitmap));
            }
            /*
             * byte[] rawBytes = result.getRawBytes(); BarcodeFormat format =
             * result.getBarcodeFormat(); ResultPoint[] points =
             * result.getResultPoints();
             */

        } catch (NotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ChecksumException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FormatException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return textResult;
    }// end decodeBitmapToString (BinaryBitmap bitmap)

    public BinaryBitmap cameraBytesToBinaryBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        BinaryBitmap binaryBitmap = null;
        if (bitmap != null) {

            int[] pixels = new int[bitmap.getHeight() * bitmap.getWidth()];
            bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth() - 1,
                    bitmap.getHeight() - 1, bitmap.getWidth(),
                    bitmap.getHeight());

            RGBLuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(
                    bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), pixels);

            HybridBinarizer bh = new HybridBinarizer(source);
            binaryBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(bh);
        } else {
            Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity , cameraBytesToBinaryBitmap (Bitmap bitmap): bitmap = ",
                    String.valueOf(bitmap));
        }

        return binaryBitmap;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    /*
     * The method getScreenOrientation() return screen orientation either
     * landscape or portrait. IF width < height , than orientation = portrait,
     * ELSE landscape For backwards compatibility we use to methods to detect
     * the orientation. The first method is for API versions prior to 13 or
     * HONEYCOMB.
     */
    public int getScreenOrientation() {

        int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        // if API version less than 13
        Display getOrient = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        int orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED;

        if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            // Do something for API version less than HONEYCOMB

            if (getOrient.getWidth() == getOrient.getHeight()) {
                orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_SQUARE;
            } else {
                if (getOrient.getWidth() < getOrient.getHeight()) {
                    orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
                } else {
                    orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Do something for API version greater or equal to HONEYCOMB

            Point size = new Point();
            this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
            int width = size.x;
            int height = size.y;

            if (width < height) {
                orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
            } else {
                orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
            }
        }

        return orientation;

    }// end getScreenOrientation()
}// end class activity
```

**layout for the activity "ScanVinFromBarcodeActivity" , activity_barcode_vin_scanner.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dip" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="20dip"
        android:text="@string/decode_label"
        android:textColor="@color/mbackground1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/mbackground2"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="20dip"
        android:textColor="@color/mytextcolor" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="20dip"
        android:text="@string/continue_label"
        android:textColor="@color/mytextcolor" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/webbutton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/web_button"
        android:textColor="@color/mytextcolor" />

    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/FrameLayoutForPreview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/surfaceViewBarcodeScanner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What device are you experiencing this on?

Comment: Galaxy S3. So whats the solution, how can I hack this to work properly. I can put Galaxy S specific logic? Its seems p.setRotation(90); , has no effect.

Comment: Only this device? And have you checked the video?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you call mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90) before you call setPreviewDisplay in your surfaceCreated method this should fix the SurfaceView orientation but the image rotation will still be wrong.

I'm currently working on a Nexus 7 and Galaxy S3 and calling setRotation(270) on the camera parameters with the Nexus (front-facing camera only) fixes the image rotation. This setter seems to have no effect on the S3.

What I'm doing at the moment is rotating the image itself 90 degrees in the onPictureTaken handler, for a front-facing camera the rotation needs to be anti-clockwise (-90):

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(90);
Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bmpWidth, bmpHeight, matrix, true);
```

This works for the two devices I mentioned, but I am concerned as to how this will behave on other devices.

Comment: @ RocketRonz, the preview correctly displaying now, Thanks. I haven't tried the matrix operation but I try it & use a file writer to see if the saved image is also in the correct orientation. Thanks